# Understanding time-domain tecnique for the calculation of black hole quasi normal modes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I am working on black hole quasi normal mode, in particular I am working on the time domain tecnique for the calculation of QNM. I am studying [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9307009) by Carsten Gundlach, Richard Price, Jorge Pullin, the one that introduced the time domain tecnique for the study of black hole perturbations.

I have been strugglin on this for 2 days, but I do not understand their section II, in which they calculate the expression for the asymptotic behavoir of the black hole; their discussion goes to fast I cannot follow the details.

Can anyone suggest a better reference, more detailed (and possibly slower)?

Or even better: can anyone try to explain it?

As I wrote in the comment, a point that I do not understand is the matching procedure between the solution at small $r$ and at large $r$. Also I do not understand which is the function that I should use for the application of the time domain tecnique: is it the solution at large distance? And moreover, is it necessary to solve the equation:

$$4\partial_u\partial_v \psi + V_l\psi=0$$

to find the function $\psi_{finstat}(r)$?

Comment: Can you try to explain what you are having trouble with? This will make it easier to point you to relevant literature.

Comment: @mmeent Most of the paper gives me trouble. For example the matching between the solutions close to the horizon and far from it